# Problem parsing the first item of array from a csv file read from inputstream

Tags: java, arrays, parseint

1. The file is read from CSV. ok
2. the String is splitted using the semicolon. ok
3. parsing first string of array returns NumberformatException. Error<

Things i've already tried:

1. Integer.Valueof(str);
2. Integer.parseInt(str);
3. pp = new Integer(str);

Could someone help with this issue? thanks

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    File inputF = new File("C:\\chatse\\Estatistica\\dados.csv");
    InputStream inputFS = new FileInputStream(inputF);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputFS));
    String line;
    String readFromCsv = "";

    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        readFromCsv += line + ";";
    }

    in.close();

    String read = readFromCsv.trim();

    String[] n = read.split(";");

    ArrayList<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String st : n) {
           lista.add(st);

    }
    ArrayList<Integer> nlistNum = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String data : lista) {

        int pp Integer.Valueof(data); //tried this,
        int pp Integer.parseInt(data); // this,
        int pp = new Integer(data); // and this.

        nlistNum.add(pp);
    }
```

Comment: Please add some data from CSV file. Need to check those

Comment: Your CSV data file may contain non-numerical values

Comment: Generally a CSV file contains rows of comma (or other character) delimited data. It can also contain a Header line as the first file line describing the data column names. You're reading your CSV file into a single string variable. Is this what your intentions are or does the CSV file contain a single column of Numbers? There is no way of knowing unless you supply a partial example of the how the data is contained within the file. Keep in mind that the Integer.parseInt() method can only handle string representation of **Integer** numbers (no alpha char's are allowed except - or + prefix).

Comment: Hello everyone, in fact the issue was that the first index of my array had a "ascii 65279", so i figured out this by trying split this index in a char array and retrieving its Length
Maybe i need declate this post as Solved, but i did not know how yet, this is my fisrt post

Answer (score 0):

> issue was that the first index of my array had a "ascii 65279", so i
>   figured out this by spliting this index in a char array and retrieving
>   its Length

```
n = readFromCsv.split(";");

for (String st : n) {

    char[] charr = st.toCharArray();
    String str = "";
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (char c : charr) {
        int asci = (int) c;
        //this verify if it is in the range of number
        if (asci >= 48 && asci <= 57) {
            sb.append(c);
        }
    }
    str = sb.toString();
    int novoInt = Integer.valueOf(str);
    nlistNum.add(novoInt);
}
```